# Pattern Brushes in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am struggling with creating various brushes to fill in various shapes or as a background.  Here are some patterns I am struggling with creating:

1. <<<<>>>>
2. <|<|<|<|>|>|>|>
3. ////////
4. \\\\
5. ||||||||

I've been able to create the \\\, //////, and |||||| with a linear gradient, but the first two are causing me issues. BTW, the second one is a triangle.

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a [`TileBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.tilebrush.aspx#remarksToggle). Define the pattern of one tile with a `Drawing` or an image, and repeat it with a `DrawingBrush` or `ImageBrush`. The documentation is quite extensive on this subject, the examples should give you some ideas

Comment: It wasn't exactly what I was hoping for, but I was able to get close to what I wanted.  I used a DrawingBrush with a DrawingGeometry that included the line segments for the various lines.  Here are the patterns: /\/\/\/\/ >>>>>> xxxxxxx

Answer (score 5):

You can create composite gradients using a drawing brush.  For example, here is a diamond gradient that you can paste into a window for testing:

```
<Window.Background>
    <DrawingBrush>
        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup>
                <DrawingGroup.Children>
                    <GeometryDrawing>
                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,100,100"/>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                                <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="Black" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="White" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing>
                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="100,0,100,100"/>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="Black" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="White" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing>
                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,100,100,100"/>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,1" EndPoint="1,0">
                                <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="Black" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="White" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing>
                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="100,100,100,100"/>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1,1" EndPoint="0,0">
                                <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="Black" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="White" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                </DrawingGroup.Children>
            </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    </DrawingBrush>
</Window.Background>
```

ASCII graphics aren't expressive enough but maybe this is what you meant by <<<>>>:

[image]

Comment: Actually I was looking a stripe like pattern and not a gradient.

Comment: Same idea then: use a drawing brush with multiple striped linear gradients.  Seems like you already figured out how to create striped gradients but for everyone else here's an example of how to do that: http://blog.pixelingene.com/?p=276